Second order differential equation with ln
I have a differential equation I need help solving


$$f''(x)-(a^2+B\ln(x))f(x)=0$$

where a and B are constants.


I know f(x) must be e to the power of something but no exponents works correctly. I got the equation from a Schrödinger equation after I plugged in the potential energy. Is there even an analytical solution? I'm not sure how to solve it so any help will be appreciated!

You will clearly have problems if $x \le 0$, but otherwise there will be a solution for a given starting point, whether it is in closed form or not.

Have you looked at Murphy’s Ordinary Differential Equations and Their Solutions? In the meantime, Henry is correct about the existence of a solution.

If $B=0$, then $f(x)=c_1 e^{|a|x}+c_2 e^{-|a|x}$ (except when $a$ also equals $0$, which is a trivial case anyway), but, as also stated below by Robert Israel, I have doubts that any other value of $B$ produces an analytic solution.

If you write $f(x) = \exp(g(x))$ the differential equation becomes
$$ g''(x) + (g'(x))^2 - a^2 - B \ln(x) = 0 $$
Thus $h(x) = g'(x)$ satisfies the first-order differential equation
$$ h'(x) + h(x)^2 - a^2 - B \ln(x) = 0 $$
That is a Riccati differential equation, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be one that has a closed-form solution.  Maple doesn't find a closed-form solution.
